# Can't register an application in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Since yesterday I can't add and application to my tenant or look at the properties of an already added application.
Also if I try to delete the directory I can't because it says I have to delete all the applications in the directory first, when I click to view the applications.... there are none...
Is there a problem going on with the service? Is there somewhere else I can find about this?

Comment: Have you tried others, like users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Martin. It was a service issue. You can use B2C service blog

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureadb2c/2018/11/28/investigating-administrators-are-unable-to-create-new-b2c-applications-or-modify-the-permissions-for-existing-b2c-applications/

Please confirm the issue was fixed for you.

Comment: Thank you! Yes. It started working again two days later!